# NameError: name 'close' is not defined error using Selenium Webdriver through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

It keeps show me the same error:

> NameError: name 'close' is not defined

I tried also with `quit()` and it works, but i need to close just one browser.

Code:

```
def browser_func():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    username = "USER"
    password = "PASS"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/cimin/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
    driver.get("LINK")
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")
    element.send_keys(username)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")
    element.send_keys(password)
    element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="module-2970"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/span')
    element.click()
    if input('done?') == 'y':
        close()

browser_func()
```

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for Python 3.x -

```
driver.close()
```

quit() is a Python keyword and instead of suspending selenium it will exit the Python program altogether. 
Try 'driver.close()' or 'driver.quit()' for closing selenium tabs. 
[More info here](https://www.edureka.co/community/43074/what-is-the-difference-between-driver-close-and-driver-quit)

Answer (score 1):

`close()` method is defined as a remote webdriver method.

- [`close()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.close): Closes the current window.

So effectively you need to stop calling:

```
close()
```

and invoke `close()` method through the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance, i.e. *driver* as follows:

```
driver.close()
```